# Repair Hard Drive That was in the Middle of a DD zeroing when Machine Powered Off

Tags: hard-disk, dd, hardware

I am unable to access a hard drive that was in the middle of zeroing with dd command when an accident resulted in powering off the machine. I cannot access the hard drive with fdisk, gparted, dd, etc. I get IO errors.

I am wondering if there is a way to repair it?

From dmesg, I get thousands of errors like this:

```
[10887.147513] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#31 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[10887.147515] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#31 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[10887.147518] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#31 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 74 70 6d 00 00 00 08 00
[10887.147521] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1953524992 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
```

When I

```
[someuser@somehost ~]$ sudo smartctl -a -d scsi /dev/sda
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.6.6-300.fc32.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

User Capacity:        1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Physical block size:  4096 bytes
LU is fully provisioned
Rotation Rate:        5400 rpm
Form Factor:          2.5 inches
Logical Unit id:      0x5000039535d0c3fe
Serial number:        Z3TFS3TUS
Device type:          disk
Local Time is:        Tue Jun  9 21:57:37 2020 EDT
SMART support is:     Unavailable - device lacks SMART capability.

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
Current Drive Temperature:     0 C
Drive Trip Temperature:        0 C

Error Counter logging not supported


[GLTSD (Global Logging Target Save Disable) set. Enable Save with '-S on']
Device does not support Self Test logging
```

I am not interested in recovering any data, but merely in fixing the disk so that I can continue to use it.

Are there any magic commands that may help me?

Thank you

Comment: 1 TB and no SMART is unusual. Guess: the power off event destroyed some hardware, und now the microcontroller is acting erratic. Not much you can do, even if the hardware/firmware allows recovery, because that is pretty much undocumented by the manufacturer.